# Disappearing error message and Safari windows

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

When I close my laptop I have it set to automatically log me off. I closed my laptop while I still had some Safari browser windows open along with my iTunes.

When i opened it, I logged back on. I moved into my space with my Safari browsers, however I could not interact with any of them. When changing spaces and then coming back to it, I saw an window pop-up asking me if I wanted to quit Safari and all 4 browsers that very quickly disappeared.

I did not want to quit Safari, but because it disappeared so fast all I could do was change spaces to make it reappear and then press enter to make it go away, and lose my browsers.

Why did this happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure that we have enough information to help you solve your problem -- unless someone here happens to have run into the same problem you had.  By `automatically log me off` do you mean that it actually logs your user out completely, or does it just lock the screen, requiring your username and password to unlock it?

Comment: no it just locks my screen, but this dosent seem like its the first time this has happened. I think this happens occasionally with mac but i do not know why

Comment: @luca590 It could be a bug related to your computer sleeping while using Safari in Spaces.  (Say that ten times, fast...)  If so, it might be tough to pin down since there's no concrete crash log data.  Next time this happens, try accessing the Safari windows by clicking the Safari icon in your Dock, regardless of what Space you're in.  If that doesn't work, try holding a click on the Dock icon to reveal all Safari windows.

Comment: i think it might just have to do with my computer sleeping and using Safari in general, but i will try to open it in a different space next time anyway, and im sure it is a bug, but it just seems like its something apple would have fixed considering im using the "new" macbook pro with 10.6.7, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @luca as an additional test you can try to use cmd+´ to change between open windows (after clicking Safari's Dock icon) to see if that brings focus to something you can't see.

Comment: oh no i dont need to zoom in, its not like the message is too small. It just disappears extremely fast but it doesnt exit out of it. So my mac is still expecting me to click cancel or close all browsers (i.e its not letting me click anything else) but i cannot because the error message is no longer on the screen